# Trigger to enforce constraint: Make sure 2 Npc_id cannot have the same item_id

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Don't mind the red numbers, I am making a trigger to enforce constraints. I want to make sure that 2 different npc_id in the Merchants table cannot have the same item_id. I'm lost on how to do it, any help would be much appreciated!
[My ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z35bN.png)

Comment: Unique constraint on npc_id and item_id?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
alter table merchants add (
    constraint my_constraint_name unique (npc_id, item_id)
);
```

Also, are you sure your `city_id` shouldn't be in the `npcs` table?